# Why is my Xcode simulator just showing me a black screen? No scene delegate set?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I've seen a similar question before but the post was very old and none of the answers worked for me. I am making a really simple code for cs50's mobile track which is just a tiny pokedex, but whenever I run my app simulator, I am met with a black screen instead of the app.

Here is what it says in the debugger if that helps: `There is no scene delegate set. A scene delegate class must be specified to use a main storyboard file.`

AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

SceneDelegate:

```
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }


}
```

info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                    <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                    <string>Main</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Are you using a storyboard?  Is `ViewController` set to be the initial view controller?  If those seem OK, try using Xcode's view debugger to find out what it thinks is on the screen.

Comment: @PhillipMills I added the message that it gave me to my original post. If you could help me understand that and tell me what it wants me to do that would be great.

Comment: You are showing us the wrong code. What we need to see is the app delegate, the scene delegate, and the Info.plist. Also main.swift if there is one.

Comment: @matt I added app and scene delegate. I'm new to Xcode and swift so I'm not sure how to share info.plist properly but I added it as source code. No main.swift

Comment: Perfect!!!! Unfortunately I don't see why that would give you the dreaded black screen. :( Can you post the project at github or similar and I'll figure it out for you.

Comment: @Tyler The problem for you and me is that it looks like the OP started with the app template, so it's hard to see where anything could have gone wrong.

Comment: Yeah, clever, if you're right I'll buy you a virtual beer

Comment: @Tyler That's not it the box is checked I haven't done anything to either scene or app delegate

Comment: @matt I'm struggling with figuring out how to upload my Xcode to github so it might take a while longer.

Comment: No worries, we'll figure it out, stay calm :)

Comment: @matt I finally got it to work: https://github.com/meematzz/pokedex/tree/master/Pok%C3%A9dex

Comment: Cool let me grab it and see what the deal is

Comment: Ooops no you forgot the project file. You needed to be one level up and check _that_ folder in to github.

Comment: @matt I added everything that I could in now. Sorry!

Comment: Yep, nailed it, I see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `é` in the name of your project. Don't do that.

Keep in mind that the project name is not user-facing. You can call the *app* by a name that has an `é` in it, but don't attempt to start a project with a name like that. Bad Things will happen (and you just encountered one of them).

I suggest that you just start all over. That will be easier than trying to rename the project and all that relates to it.

Answer (score 0):

> `There is no scene delegate set. A scene delegate class must be specified to use a main storyboard file.`

I've also encountered this error message as a result of having my `SceneDelegate` class conform to the `UISceneDelegate` protocol rather than `UIWindowSceneDelegate` (*an error that resulted from an incorrect autocompletion*).